# What is PocoCapsule current status?

Tags: c++, inversion-of-control

What is [PocoCapsule](http://code.google.com/p/pococapsule/) current status? Is it evolving? Has it been forked
with some other product?
What is about the whole idea of IoC for C++? If PocoCapsule is not
evolving, is it because IoC was considered not useful for C++, unsafe,
other patterns appeared or something else?

As far as I understand there are 2-3, maybe few more products, that
implement IoC for C++, available and
PocoCapsule is the most mature of them.

I see several disadvantages in current version (as I see it's 1.1 from
google code):

1. No separate namespace.
2. Header files are required to be right in INCLUDE folder - better to place them in subfolder.
3. Generation Tools depend on Java.
4. No static linking libraries are built by default.
5. Cannot generate source code out of setup.xml for compilation and link with my app if I don't need reconfiguration feature.

Does anybody have the same thoughts? Does anybody work on something of
this list? Are there any barriers to start working, like patents?

Answer (score 3):

I emailed Ke Jin (maintainer) and his response was that it is not under current, active development as of Jul 14, 2011. He did not give a reason.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for this myself for some time now, and came realize that there are no good IoC Containers in C++. There are a lot of problems implementing this. Getting something like the C# IoC Containers (Castle Windsor, Unity, etc.) is out of reach. My guess is that if you require something like this, you don´t do c++. And if you do C++, you roll your own or use singleton factories (little joke) ;)

An easy shortcut is to use Qt´s QML. It was build for declarative UIs but can be used for building any QObject based tree.

Another good look are CORBA Systems for C++, they may have some of the things you require.

Just my hints for other places to look...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can successfully use Qt metaobject system by reusing QtCore library and moc-compiler in your application.

With metaobject system you can create fully isolated modules by calling any method of module's interface via [QMetaObject::invokeMethod()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod).

And all will work without QCoreApplication object instance! Define your modules as subclasses of QObject, provide Q_OBJECT macro and mark all interface methods with Q_INVOKABLE ( of course, you should add moc-compiler as build step ).